# how to iterate over rows in dataframe and access the specific column at each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to access all the rows of a dataframe if the "match" column is "False".

Since I can't upload an image, I will explain the data. The dataframe has several columns, and I am only interested in the "match" column. I will keep all the rows when the "match" column's values are "False"

[image: [enter image description here]]

```sh
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome SIYAN. Instead of uploading the image, you could post the code. It helps others to copy and paste your code and run it locally.

Comment: You must have hit your CAPS LOCK key prior to typing "fALSE" which is not a Python key word. Just need to change to "False" and that should clear your error.

Comment: You don't need to do this, this is what [**boolean filtering**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection) by a logical expression is for: `df23[df23['match'] == False]` or `df23[~ df23['match']]` to be concise.

Comment: @mgrollins: yes but the bigger picture is noone should ever write manual selection code like this when panads supports `df23[~ df23['match']]` i.e. Boolean indexing

Comment: This is a duplicate, see [piRSquared's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165056/202229)

Comment: @smci I agree, but being new to pandas myself, there are so many mistakes one can make that obscure why a specific approach is or is not working, I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @mgrollins: but when someone asks the right syntax to do something the wrong way, first tell them very loud and clear that it's the wrong way, tell them what the right way they need is, only then tell them "oh and by the way here's the syntax for what you were trying to do". Otherwise you only multiply confusion. There's too much of that in the pandas tag already. Also, this is a dupe. No point in answering dupes - they will get promptly closed. If they don't get promptly closed, come tell us in the [Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @smci! I haven't used the chatroom, but I will give it a try in the future!

Comment: @mgrollins: Cool. Please skim the [Python chatroom rules](https://sopython.com/chatroom) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this, this is what [**boolean filtering**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection) by a logical expression is for:

```
df23[df23['match'] == False]
```

or to be more concise:

```
df23[~ df23['match']]
```